# Why are there multiple levels of dependecies in aspnet5 project.json?

Tags: .net-core, coreclr

Why in the project.json is there a “dependencies” element outside of any of the target “frameworks”?  When do dependencies go there versus under \frameworks\net451\frameworkAssemblies or \frameworks\dnxcore50\dependencies

```
    "frameworks": {
        "net451": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System": "4.0.0.0",
            }
        },
        "dnxcore50": {
****        "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
                "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23516",
            }
        }
    },
****"dependencies": {
      "System.Diagnostics.Tools": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.Threading.Timer": "4.0.1-beta-23516"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

- Each framework (net451/dnxcore50) can have different dependencies. Let's say that you are porting a legacy app that depends on some 3rd party NuGet library that's only available for desktop CLR. In that case you can add it to the dependencies in `net451` and then mock it for `dnxcore50`. That way, you'll not get compilation errors.
- `frameworkAssemblies` vs `dependencies` = GAC vs NuGet packages. `frameworkAssemblies` is only available for desktop CLR and it is used to reference GAC assmblies.

Comment: Yes, but there's also a dependencies section that is neither under net451 nor dnxcore50. What is it for?